# Print data form Json

Tags: javascript, json

I have such json file, called file.json

```
var data = {"report":{"reference":"NN340821","identityModule":{"companyId":"340820976","refId":"A08U06V99","nic":"00017","vat":"FR05340820976","acronym":"SADIA","officialCompanyName":"SOC ADMINIST DIRECT INDUSTR ALIMENTAIRES","headEstablishment":{"phoneNumber":"0298040105","faxNumber":"0298040749","ADREEEEESSSSSSSSSSS":{"@wayName":"Saint Sebastien","@country":"France","@deliveryAddress":"Saint Sebastien","@postalDelivery":"29870 LANNILIS"},
```

In project, witch i have i need add this file and than put from it "ADREEEEESSSSSSSSSSS" object. How i can do it without ajax, only attach this file in html. 
Please, help me to solved this problem

Comment: Ehmm... Its not clear to me what you want to accomplish. Do you want to show the `ADRESS` in some HTML output?

Answer (score 2):

First, that's not JSON, it's a proper JavaScript file describing a nested JavaScript object.

Second, it's incomplete and you will get syntax errors trying to load it. Here's a corrected version:

```
var data = {
    "report": {
        "reference": "NN340821",
        "identityModule": {
            "companyId": "340820976",
            "refId": "A08U06V99",
            "nic": "00017",
            "vat": "FR05340820976",
            "acronym": "SADIA",
            "officialCompanyName": "SOC ADMINIST DIRECT INDUSTR ALIMENTAIRES",
            "headEstablishment": {
                "phoneNumber": "0298040105",
                "faxNumber": "0298040749",
                "ADREEEEESSSSSSSSSSS": {
                    "@wayName": "Saint Sebastien",
                    "@country": "France",
                    "@deliveryAddress": "Saint Sebastien",
                    "@postalDelivery": "29870 LANNILIS"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So, rename it file.js, include it in your HTML file in the `head` element where scripts generally go, before any other scripts/code that might use it.

```
<script src="file.js"></script>
```

Then you can access the address object simply with:

```
var address = data.report.identityModule.headEstablishment.ADREEEEESSSSSSSSSSS;
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2c68nuhe/)

Comment: if i have such data in json file, how i can get it?
`"scoreModule":{"actualScore":{"score":
{"@scoreAlphaLib":"Cessation","@scoreLib":"Cessation d'activité","@mergedScore":"CESS","#text":"0"}..`
I need @scoreLib data

Comment: @qweqweqweqwe, using the example I provided you should be able to work it out.